# How to cast fake data for testing against an enum column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, enums

I transform a dataframe in my transformer.py with 2 columns (id and createdAt), and I added a 3rd with:

```
class ColorType(Enum):
      LIGHT = 'LIGHT'
      def __str__(self):
          return self.name
data["colorType"] = ColorType
```

I now want to test my transformer so in my test_transformer.py I have the following:

```
record = utils.EXTRACTED_RECORD #fake raw data
result = transformer.transform_columns(record)
expected = pd.DataFrame([
              "id": 111111, 
              "completedAt":"2030-06-26T19:08:38.056Z",
              "colorType":"(LIGHT)")]
testing.assert_frame_equal(result,expected)
```

When I run this test, I get thrown the following error:

```
AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 2] (column name="colorType" values are different (100.0%)
[index]: [0, 1]
[left]: [(LIGHT), (LIGHT)]
[right]: [(LIGHT), (LIGHT)]
```

My question is, how do I correctly mock the "colorType" column as an enum in my fake data (the "expected" dataframe) to correctly assert my transformed data is equal? Eliminating the entire column in both the transformer and test runs perfectly.